# How to add relational entity column in sonata admin list

Tags: symfony, symfony-sonata

I have two entities Customer and Customer Contact (one-to-one bi-directional). I would like to display few fields from customer contact in the customer admin list. Can any one help with it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a custom template for that field, check out this page for more details: http://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/list_field_definition.html#advance-usage

Answer (score 1):

this is a perfect scenario, i wish i had the same with user/customer assoc in sonata:)
anyways all you have to do is (in customer admin)

```
    ->add('fieldFromCustomerEntity')
    ->add('contact.fieldFromContactEntity')
```